# Simulate tapping UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, uilabel, bdd

In my BDD tests I can simulate tapping a button using the following category:

```
@implementation UIControl (Specs)

- (void)specsSimulateTap {
    [self sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

@end
```

How do I do something similar for a UILabel with a gesture recogniser?

Ideally, I want to be able to type something along the following in my code:

```
[myLabel specsSimulateTap]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you want to do is possible. From looking at the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer`, there doesn't seem to be a public API for even capturing the target/action.

You can use private APIs to call these methods, but you'd want to ensure that any use of private APIs never occur in your build for the App Store. There is a [comment on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17320523/816002) the shows how to do this.

Using private APIs is generally a bad idea, as if Apple changes behaviour behind the scenes it may cause your tests to fail. Perhaps take a step back and think about exactly what you're wanting to test here.

Comment: I'm trying to test the behaviour of the app and that behaviour is that when the user taps the label, a webview opens. I could just call the target function from my test but then its not testing the true scenario. However, sometimes you can't always do things "perfect".